# .DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value

Tags: django

```
(mydjango) C:\StockMarketResearch\Else\StockAnalysisApp>python manage.py dbshell
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\mydjango\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\mydjango\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 330, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\mydjango\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 390, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\mydjango\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 441, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\mydjango\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\dbshell.py", line 19, in handle
    connection.client.runshell()
  File "C:\mydjango\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\dummy\base.py", line 21, in complain
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. "
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the ENGINE value. Check settings documentation for more details
```

Database setting:

```
DATABASES = {
'default':{
},
'stock':{
    'NAME': 'STOCK',
    'ENGINE': 'sqlserver_ado',
    'HOST': 'EC2AMAZ-L7EBVJV\SQLEXPRESS1',
    'USER': 'sa',
    'PASSWORD': 'XXX',
    'OPTIONS': {
                'provider': 'SQLOLEDB',
                'use_legacy_date_fields': True,
                #'MARS_Connection': True
            }
}
```

this error occurs only when I try python manage.py dbshell/migrate/syncdb
but
I am able to execute simple database queries like 
**select * from xyz** *(without any error or warning)*
but not able to run queries like 
**insert into abc(x, c) 
select x,c from pqr** this gives me error **trying to fetch from a closed connection or empty set**
And again I am able to execute nested queries without error

Comment: I have already specified the ENGINE value in settings file.

Comment: can you show ur settings.py db code

Comment: @NischalGote: Please show us your settings.py file in order to see the database settings.

Comment: Add the database section to your description, and not in the comments.

Comment: Is `django-mssql` correctly installed? i.e. `pip install django-mssql`

Comment: yes its correctly installed (version 1.8 both for django and django-mssql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your databases set doesn't contain a complete definition for the `default` dict, its just an empty dict.

Either copy your definition for `stock` into default (preferably set to a variable that is then set to both definitions) or define it

Comment: Not necessarily. According to the docs,  Django requires that a default database entry be defined, but the parameters dictionary can be left blank if it will not be used. To do this, you must set up DATABASE_ROUTERS for all of your apps’ models, including those in any contrib and third-party apps you’re using, so that no queries are routed to the default database. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/multi-db/

Comment: @Frankline - Good point, from the given information it is probable that the OP hasn't defined any routers but definitely something that should be considered (and updated in the question if so)

Comment: removing 'default' gives error **must define default**

Comment: @NischalGote - Ah oops, I thought django would just take the  only other db left, you're best option is just to define it.

Comment: After copying the same in both it gives another error 
    NotImplementedError: subclasses of BaseDatabaseClient must provide a runshell() method

Comment: I left the 'S' off of DATABASE'S' and yah... Thats how my day is going.